# Create a view to display all nodes referencing this content

Tags: views, entities

I have 2 content types: *Recipe* and *Product*. In *Recipe*, I have an entity refence field to select a *Product* node used from the *Recipe* node.

In the *Product* node, I want to create a view to list all the recipes using that product. This means a block which lists all the recipes that reference this product.

How can I achieve this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake :

In Relationship, I have to select the entity reference field used in Recipe. 
In contextual, I select NID as usual but I have to use the Relationship I've just created. Then I select Provide default value (ID from url).

I don't need to use this relationship in the Fields I add.